# Winforms open console in Main without closing form?

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I have made an application in C# that uses both a form and a console, called in the Main() from Program.cs:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if (Form1.compile == 0)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }

        if (Form1.compile == 1)
        {
            Form1.compile = 0;
            int u;

            IntPtr ptr = GetForegroundWindow();

            GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out u);

            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(u);
            AllocConsole();

            //a lot of code for the command prompt
        }
}
```

When starting the application, it first starts Form1. Then when Form1 is closed, and only then, it loads up the command prompt and all the code I put into it.

My question is, how could I run the second part (when compile == 1) just by pressing a button in Form1? Is it even possible, as the Main() function only gets called on start, and Application.Start(Program.Main()) gives an error?

Button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Close();  // Any way to open the console part without closing the form?         
     //this.Hide();
       compile = 1;
    }
```

Note: I tried calling opening Form1 AFTER the console, but I also want to update the console whenever I press the button, which doesn't happen.

EDIT: For future readers, the solution was simply to put everything in the mainform (or another class) instead of Main(), as it didn't update itself, thus not being able to do anything after launch.

Comment: is it compile is static ??

Comment: I called compile from Form1, so it is static. The Main() function simply doesn't update, and I want it to update whenever I press the button in Form1.

Comment: Just calling Application.Exit() is enough.  this.Close() is a very decent second choice, quite unclear why that doesn't cause the Application.Run() call to complete.

Comment: @Hans Okay, I initially thought Application.Exit() would close both the form and the console.

Comment: Application.Exit() will cause the `Run()` to complete and close all open windows, so it should work. I have one question: Why don't you just start the console when your Window is closing from the GUI-Part of the application?

Comment: At the moment, the console opens on the window close, but because the window is like the IDE, and the console the compiled program in runtime, I want them both to stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be pulling the code for dealing with the console out of your `Main` method.  Create a new class responsible for creating/manipulating the console in your program and copy the code you have inside of `Form1.compile == 1` into that class.  Then in `Main` just call out to that class if it should be creating a console, or call out to it from a button click event if that is when you want to create and then manipulate a console.

Comment: But then I would still have to update Main, to check if the button is pressed? And Main won't update unless the original created form gets closed

Comment: @Bart It's unclear if you should never create the console from `Main` or only conditionally.  If you *only* want to show the console from a button click, just remove all of your code from `Main` entirely.  If you sometimes want to show the console before, after, or instead of showing the form, then you'll need to have code in `Main`.

Comment: Okay, I will just create the console inside the form then, removing all of the code out of Main(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do that as follows without touching the main().

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AllocConsole();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AllocConsole();
            this.Hide();
            // Just call the console related methods in here
        }
```

Comment: Not trying to be offensive , but I don't think I totally understand you, because of how you talk. Could you possibly give a code example?

Comment: Why would this work instead of simply Form1.compile? It also gives an error: compile cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me just try and explain what is actually happening.

The Main method is executed sequentially, just as you would expect. It executes one command, then the next etc. However, as soon as you call Application.Run, you're starting a message loop - basically, a large `while (true) { ... }`. This continues as long as the form is open. So, if you want something done while the form is open, don't put it behind the Application.Run call, just put it in your button's Click event handler.

Now, I guess you want to be able to open a console when you press the button, but even when the button *hasn't* been pressed.

The simplest way is to create a helper class for your console:

```
public static class ConsoleHelper
{
  static bool isCreated;

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  private static extern bool AllocConsole();

  public static void PrepareConsole()
  {
    if (isCreated) return;

    AllocConsole();
    isCreated = true;
  }
}
```

Now, you just call ConsoleHelper.PrepareConsole() when you press your button.

If you haven't pressed a button, though, it will obviously not create the console. You can remove the console initialization code from your Main function, just call ConsoleHelper.PrepareConsole() in your Form's Closing event handler. This way, you should have console on demand in the form, as well as after closing the form.

If that isn't what you want, you're probably going to have to explain yourself better, since apparently, there's enough ambiguity to get three answers that don't answer your question :D

Comment: A bit late, but thanks for your explanation. I have not tested this, as I already managed to get what I wanted.